# SSRS set background color of cell based on background color of another cell

Tags: reporting-services, colors, cell

I want a table cell in child row to take on the background color of the cell in the groupby row.
It is possible to reference the text box which exists in the parent group and so i have used it in n expression to set the background colour of the child.
e.g.
Parent has background set to "red"
in the Background colour of the child cell i added this expression 
=Fields!DerivedReportDate.BackgroundColor

it doesn't error but also ignores the statement and remaines with no color.

Anyone know if this is possible ?

ErickTreetops

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be possible.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx

If you have a reasonable number of groups, just match them manually.
If you have an unreasonable number of groups, use the same conditional formula to modify the backgrounds of the groups at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround - you could possibly make another field called `BackgroundColor` that accepts `string` values. You can set this in your code/database for the parent. Then, in the BackgroundColor property in Properties pane, enter the expression `=Fields!BackgroundColor.Value`. The you could use the same field for child by using `Lookup` expressions. [Heres more about Lookup](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/bidn-blog/2037/lookup-and-lookupset-functions-new-in-ssrs-2008-r2)

Answer (score 0):

ok.  I decided it was too hard or possily impossible with to do this on the reporting services side so i ammended my SQL statement so that i got a 1 or 0 for each group and those child records associated to the group.  Here is the query.

SELECT a.ServiceDriverServiceID, a.IndicatorName,b.ServiceDriverName,b.DerivedReportDate,b.Value,x.rowcolour
from [dbo].[SLA_ServiceDriver_ServiceNames] a 
join [dbo].[FileShare_ServiceDrivers_Services] b on a.ServiceDriverServiceID = b.ServiceDriverServiceID and  a.ServiceName = @serviceName
 join 
(
select derivedreportdate, (row_number() over(order by DerivedReportDate))%2 as rowcolour
from [dbo].[SLA_ServiceDriver_ServiceNames] a 
join [dbo].[FileShare_ServiceDrivers_Services] b on a.ServiceDriverServiceID = b.ServiceDriverServiceID
where a.ServiceName = @serviceName
group by derivedreportdate

) x on b.DerivedReportDate = x.DerivedReportDate
order by b.DerivedReportDate desc

I used 1 and zero's but could have made the rowcolour a case statement which returned the string equivalent of a colour depending on the row value.